# How to Use MMS to Manage MongoDB Instance Installed with MUP

Tags: meteor, meteor-up, mongodb-mms

I'm relatively inexperienced with sysadmin work, but I'm trying to figure out how to connect MMS to my Meteor app to sync regular backups of our MongoDB instance. The app was deployed on Digital Ocean using MUP, but MMS doesn't seem to want to connect to the Mongo Instance. I was wondering if there are any specific steps that need to be taken to make MMS work properly. It appears as though MMS requires standalone instances to be reconfigured to be replica instances, but I'm not quite sure how this works. I was wondering if anyone else has gone through this and could assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MMS to be able to manage your servers remotely you need to install the MMS Automation Agent on each server that's running MongoDB, and you need to have specific ports open so they can access the automation agent.

Use the [instructions for installing the agent on your specific operating system](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/tutorial/nav/install-automation-agent/).

Also use the [MMS Automation Checklist](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/core/automation-checklist/) to make sure you have everything configured properly.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I think there is an issue with the mongod instance being installed as a standalone instance vs as a part of a replica set. In addition, MUP installs mongo so that it can only be accessed locally. Are you aware of this causing issues?